# fatal: bad revision '$GIT_COMMIT''

Tags: windows, git, git-filter-branch

I just want to see the content of `GIT_COMMIT` variable over each commit:

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'echo $GIT_COMMIT' -- --all
```

I get this error:

```
WARNING: git-filter-branch has a glut of gotchas generating mangled history
         rewrites.  Hit Ctrl-C before proceeding to abort, then use an
         alternative filtering tool such as 'git filter-repo'
         (https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/) instead.  See the
         filter-branch manual page for more details; to squelch this warning,
         set FILTER_BRANCH_SQUELCH_WARNING=1.
Proceeding with filter-branch...

fatal: bad revision '$GIT_COMMIT''
```

How should I fix this?

Comment: I guess it is because variables are not expanded inside single quotes. Try using double quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on Windows in a CMD, then yes, as [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66132463/fatal-bad-revision-git-commit/66133702#comment116921174_66132463) by [Marc Luzzara](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5587393/marco-luzzara), using double-quotes helps.

But the actual error message, with single quotes in a CMD shell, would be:

```
set FILTER_BRANCH_SQUELCH_WARNING=1

git filter-branch --tree-filter 'echo $GIT_COMMIT' @

fatal: ambiguous argument '$GIT_COMMIT'': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'


# or, as mentioned in the OP

git filter-branch --tree-filter 'echo $GIT_COMMIT' -- --all
fatal: bad revision '$GIT_COMMIT''
```

The same command works in a `git bash` session:

```
$ git filter-branch --tree-filter 'echo $GIT_COMMIT' -- --all
Rewrite 92a741579ad31e6ccb17fda876e084b181bbdcdb (1/4) (0 seconds passed, remaining 0 predicted)    92a741579ad31e6ccb17fda876e084b181bbdcdb
...
```